# Find xlsx in a directory and assign the sheets to different dataframes - Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, glob

Junior dev here.

My goal is to get 4 different dfs created from 4 different sheets within 1 Excel file which name can vary based upon which update version is created.

This is my attempt.

```
import pandas as pd, glob

# Finds the target file in local directory
excel_file = glob.glob('file_v*.xlsx')

# Assigns specific sheet from Excel file to df
hr_df = pd.read_excel(open(excel_file, 'rb'), sheet_name='HR')
title_df = pd.read_excel(open(excel_file, 'rb'), sheet_name='Job_Family')
vendor_df = pd.read_excel(open(excel_file, 'rb'), sheet_name='Vendors')
dept_df = pd.read_excel(open(excel_file, 'rb'), sheet_name='Departments')
```

The error I'm getting is below. I understand that I can't pass a path object. **I'm confused on how to connect the recursive search into opening and assigning my dfs.**

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
```

Any suggestions and explanations are appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: `excel_file` is a list. You shopuld loop through its elements or use elements index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd, glob

# Finds the target file in local directory
excel_file = glob.glob('file_v*.xlsx')[0]

# Assigns specific sheet from Excel file to df
f = open(excel_file, 'rb')
hr_df = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name='HR')
title_df = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name='Job_Family')
vendor_df = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name='Vendors')
dept_df = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name='Departments')

f.close()
```

Comment: I think you should close the file after such operation.

Comment: I believe the file actually is closed automatically, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), but no harm is done, so I added it.

Comment: Do I have to be in the same directory for this to work? I'm getting a ```IndexError: list index out of range```

Comment: Yes, you have to be in the same directory that the excel files are in. Otherwise, you need to add the full path to the folder, e.g. `glob.glob('C:\\the\\path\\to\\the\\files\\file_v*.xlsx')[0]`

Comment: I see. Apologies I should have mentioned that at the beginning. I tried this but still getting the list index out of range error. Unfortunately, I can't have the script and the target file in the same directory.

```glob.glob('~/Downloads/file_v*.xlsx')[0]```

Comment: You can't use `~` there...you have to type your full path e.g. `/Users/davida28/Downloads/file_v*.xlsx` or whatever :)